# remoteFunction grails

Tags: ajax, grails

Hi I have a textArea and I have added a onkeyup event to it. When the event is triggered I want to update another element, by taking the input of the textArea and manipulating it in a javascript function. Here is my textArea tag:

```
<g:textArea name="translation" id="2" cols="40" rows="5" value="${domainInstance?.translation}"
                                    onkeyup="${remoteFunction(
                                    controller: 'domain',
                                    action: 'ajaxChangeTranslation',
                                    params:'\'text=\'+this.value',
                                    onComplete:'updateEntry(e)')}" />
```

and here is my stub javascript function:

```
<g:javascript>

        function updateEntry(e){
            alert("Hi");
        }
    </g:javascript>
```

My javascript function is never getting called. I never see the alert when I type something into the textArea. If I place an alert outside of the function the alert shows up. Why is my javascript function not getting called. When I ran it with the chrome debugger I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<g:textArea name="translation" id="2" cols="40" rows="5" value="${domainInstance?.translation}"
                                onkeyup="${remoteFunction(
                                controller: 'domain',
                                action: 'ajaxChangeTranslation',
                                params:'\'text=\'+this.value',
                                onComplete :'updateEntry(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus)')}" />
```

Comment: I will try that, could you explain what exactly those parameters that are getting passed to updateEntry stand for, and fyi I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not but when I made `updateEntry` into a function without any parameters it still didn't pop-up that alert

Comment: There was a javascript compilation error in your code, the variable e is not defined. The onComplete event has two parms and those are XMLHttpRequest and text status. XMLHttpRequest object is for exchange data with your server. textstatus is your status. It should also work without any params. If you use onSuccess then you can use data as  param name.

Comment: If it should work without any parameters then why didn't it pop the alert when I tried without any?